# GIS Political Townships Layer

Tags: google-maps, gis

Is it possible to obtain the political townships GIS layer that is used in Google Maps?  For example, if I search for "guilford township illinois" it highlights the outline of this township. I have searched online but cannot find it. It is slightly different than PLSS townships. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place I can think of to get this data is straight from the census.  Have a look here:  ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2008/17_ILLINOIS/17085_Jo_Daviess_County/.  The file you're looking for is tl_2008_17085_cousub.zip. I guess cousub stands for something like county subdivision, since a civil township is subordinate to the county if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could, using or obtaining that information would break the [Google's ToS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), Have you searched for the OpenStreet maps alternative?